# marquee tag still works, is it okay to use it?

Tags: html, marquee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it acceptable to use the marquee element in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964491/is-it-acceptable-to-use-the-marquee-element-in-html)

I tried, the old ancient marquee tag, and it still works. Is it okay to use it?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
    <marquee> 
        <h1>Hello</h1> 
    </marquee>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use it, but you will not be able to write valid HTML.

Comment: if you will use you will fails W3C but till now all engines supports it for now its not a problem

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee.

Comment: It wouldn't be OK to use it even if it was part of the standard...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not use `<marquee>`

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element)

> The marquee tag is a non-standard HTML element which causes text to
>   scroll up, down, left or right automatically. The tag was first
>   introduced in early versions of Microsoft's Internet Explorer, and was
>   compared to Netscape's blink element, as a proprietary non-standard
>   extension to the HTML standard with usability problems. It is
>   deprecated by the W3C and not advised by them for use in any HTML
>   documents.

Comment: Or even better, don't use either!

Comment: Don't use marquee at all - [<marquee> html tag usage/replacment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423618/marquee-html-tag-usage-replacment).

Answer (score 8):

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee

"Example: No, really. don't use it."

I think that says it all.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

You should ask: "Why not to use it?"

If you need *stuff* scrolling, then use it.
*All* browsers supports it.

**BUT** Marquee can be distracting. The human eye is attracted to movement, and marquee text is constantly moving. *(via Wiki)*

### Long answers

http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/bltags_marquee.htm

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/marquee

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element

Comment: A big reason not to use it is that you can not write valid HTML with it. Which for me is a big enough reason.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you mean by "okay".

Sure, it works in most browsers (even though not all browsers respond the same - some have different default settings, some support only a subset of the attributes; your example will work roughly the same in the majority of browsers though).

But think about the users! The poor users! Is it really OK to torture them like that? If you put marquees in your webpages, what will be next? `<blink>`?