# To zoom the images present in marquee tag on mouse hover

Tags: html, css, image, marquee

I created a simple image gallery using the marquee tag you can see it at:
 http://jsfiddle.net/gunturumanohar/62ZHC/

```
<marquee id="gallery" behavior="alternative" style="width:700px;padding:6px;" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
    <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/0/00kih8g.jpg" />
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8195/8098750703_797e102da2_z.jpg" />
</marquee>
```

and the css is:

```
#gallery img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /*Webkit: increase size to 1.5x*/
    opacity: 1; /*default opacity*/
    z-index: 10; /*place hover image in front the non-hover images*/
}
```

I zoomed the images on hover using css scale, but the problem here is when an image is scaled(zoomed) the image top and bottom are not showing.

I think the problem is with the images' parent tag, marquee.
How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: You are asking how to apply cutting edge CSS3 styles to an element that was deprecated years ago. Wait. No, it wasn't deprecated, it's never been part of *any* standard.  Answer: Don't use `<marquee/>`.

Answer (score 1):

Cool concept as an experiment, but I would recommend not using this method for a live site. While marquee is pretty well supported it is not recommended (**see** - [marquee tag still works, is it okay to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520840/marquee-tag-still-works-is-it-okay-to-use-it)). Also, there are much better ways to do this with smoother animation. That being said, I have fixed the issue for you (take or leave the advice).

```
#gallery {
    text-align: center;
    width: 610px;
    margin: -140px auto;
    padding-top: 260px;
    height: auto;
    width:700px;
}
#gallery:hover { height: 270px; }
```

It's kind of hack-ish, but so is what you're doing so I think that's probably ok.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/iancwoodward/62ZHC/1/)**