# This seamless marquee style kind of jitters each scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, marquee

I am using this code to create a scroll-up marquee text but after 7000 miliseconds it jitters and thus doesn't offer a good look for the text inside.

Have you any idea where I can fix it ?

```
<script language="javascript">
jQuery(function() {

    var marquee = jQuery("#marquee");
    marquee.css({"overflow": "hidden", "height": "100%"});
    marquee.wrapInner("<span>");
    marquee.find("span").css({ "height": "50%", "display": "inline-block", "text-align":"left" });
    marquee.append(marquee.find("span").clone());
    marquee.wrapInner("<div>");
    marquee.find("div").css("height", "200%");
    var reset = function() {
        jQuery(this).css("margin-top", "0%");
        jQuery(this).animate({ "margin-top": "-100%" }, 7000, 'linear', reset);
    };
    reset.call(marquee.find("div"));
});
```

BTW, you can it like this

```
<div id="marquee">text</div>
```

[**UPDATE**]Sorry Kamal for having to edit this post to add the jsfiddle to reproduce the problem [I always know I can do this :-D]
http://jsfiddle.net/xRcwH/

Comment: Could you try to demonstrate the problem in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Because I can't reproduce the issue. You probably didn't get an answer until now because others either can't reproduce it or didn't understand the question. Once you can reproduce it, your question will be thousands of times more likely to get a proper answer.

Comment: Ok thank you please hold on, I'm going to send you the jsfiddle id

Comment: No hurry man, you can edit the question again to add the fiddle once you've managed to reproduce the problem. `=]`

Comment: Yes, up there the update you can take a look and please offer a fix too :D

Comment: What browsers does this need to work in? There may be some solutions using css animations or the built in marquee tag that might run smoother. But you may have to stick to the current code for IE.

Comment: +1 @JefferyMills, this seems to depend on browser, font-family/size, resolution and speed. For instance, [these settings](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/xRcwH/1/) runs fine on Chrome 1680x1020, but jitters a little in Firefox.

Comment: Incredible how it works better in IE than Firefox. BTW you can edit your question whenever you want - provided you add meaningful info/code/progress or fix punctuation etc -, it's just that a good part of editors tend to "trim" posts (remove greetings, salutations and "thank you"s) whenever they see it.

Comment: To ease the reading, you can use some `text-shadow`: http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/xRcwH/4/

Answer (score 0):

why not use the `<marquee>` tags?

```
<marquee  behavior="scroll" direction="up">Your upward scrolling text goes here</marquee>
```

Comment: Because it's deprecated. See:  stackoverflow.com/questions/2227815/html-marquee-tag

Answer (score 0):

I've already answered the same question at [<marquee> html tag usage/replacment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423618/marquee-html-tag-usage-replacment/14285710#14285710).

There is CSS3 WebKit specific `-webkit-marquee-`, that you can read about at http://davidwalsh.name/webkit-marquee-css. However, for whatever reason, even the native CSS marquee implementation is glitchy.

The same applies to the `<marquee>` element. It is well supported by the browsers, though, apart from being deprecated, it is glitchy.

I've been looking for the most *efficient* and *cross-browser supported* marquee implementation. None of the above fit the bill. The common approach is to use timer (or jQuery animate implementation) to adjust the CSS margin property of the element. This is what your script does. Unfortunately, this operation is very resource intensive. It requires applying new CSS every few milliseconds resulting in recalculation of the whole layout.

I came up with implementation that utilises *CSS3 transitions* for browsers that support it and otherwise animate the `scrollLeft` property of the containing element. It is an experimental implementation, though it works well with IE7+. The code is available at https://github.com/gajus/marquee (demo https://dev.anuary.com/60244f3a-b8b2-5678-bce5-f7e8742f0c69/).