# add content to marquee every

Tags: javascript, html, json, marquee

how can i update content in marquee every 20 second using javascript?
i mean , in the first 20 seconds he **reads the first object** , on second 40 reads the second object and so on .. , without updating the page , mean update it automatically
this is the javascript function :

```
    function read () {
  $.getJSON("jsons/jobs.json", function(json) {
  Thejobs = json;
  for(var k in Thejobs.Studies){
     $('#boxContent').append('<br>'+"position: "+Thejobs.Studies[k].position+
     '<br>'+"Academy: "+Thejobs.Studies[k].academy+'<br>'+"address: "
     +Thejobs.Studies[k].address+'<br>'+"Description: "+Thejobs.Studies[k].jobDescription)
     $('#boxContent').append("<br>_____________________");
     }}); }
```

this is my json file :

```
   {"Studies": {
    "jobID1": {
        "position": "student position",
        "academy": "Haifa University",
        "address": "haifa,isreal",
        "jobDescription": "Big data"
    },
    "jobID2": {
        "position": "Research 1",
        "academy": "saarland University",
        "address": "saarbrucken , germany",
        "jobDescription": "Electronic engineer"
    },
    "jobID3": {
        "position": "Studie 1",
        "academy": "Technion",
        "address": "haifa,isreal",
        "jobDescription": "Speed of internet"
    },
    "jobID4": {
        "position": "Studie 2",
        "academy": "Technion",
        "address": "USA ,los angeles",
        "jobDescription": "analysis data "
    }
}
```

}

html file :

```
  <marquee direction="up" scrollamount="2">
  <p id="boxContent"></p>
   </marquee>
```

i've tried this but didn't work:

```
<script>
var myVar = setInterval(joobs(), 20000);
var ii=0;
function joobs(){
  $.getJSON("jsons/jobs.json", function(json) {
   Thejobs = json;
     $('#boxContent').append('<br>'+"position: 
   "+Thejobs.Studies[ii].position+
    '<br>'+"Academy: "+Thejobs.Studies[ii].academy+'<br>'+"address: "
    +Thejobs.Studies[ii].address+'<br>'+"Description: 
  "+Thejobs.Studies[ii].jobDescription)
    $('#boxContent').append("<br>_____________________");
   });
     ii=ii+1; 
      </script>
```

Comment: Don't use marquee, its obsolete and deprecated - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423618/marquee-html-tag-usage-replacment
AND
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element

Comment: If you intend to iterate through the JSON every 20 seconds `setInterval` might work. Try it out and see if it does what you need.

Comment: Where does the `Studies` come from? it's not present in your sample json.

Comment: @omid.n you are right , i've edited it sorry !

Comment: @Nope yes that's what i'm tring to do but don't know how

Comment: @CalvinNunes do you suggest to use something else?

Comment: @reeena11 https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/setInterval and your iterators will move outside of the interval I assume.

Comment: @reeena11 it's possible to keep using, it's just not correct by the rules of W3C, but here is it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951282/why-is-marquee-deprecated-and-what-is-the-best-alternative

Comment: @Nope i've edited the post, see the solution but doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't resist making this abomination.

If you need to do something at a regular interval, use [`setInterval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). Which has the signature `setInterval(callback_function, interval_in_milliseconds);` Just put your function to change the value of the `marquee` as the callback and set the interval to `20000` to delay for 20 seconds. Your function will be called every 20 seconds like in my following example.

```js
var values = ["Marquees", "shall", "never", "die.", "Long", "live", "the", "marquee!"];
var iterator = 1;
var colorator = 0;
function updateMarquee() { 
  document.getElementById('boxContent').innerHTML = values[iterator];
  iterator = (iterator + 1) % values.length;
  console.log("updateMarquee() has been called");
  
  return function() {
    console.log("updateMarquee() return value was called instead of the function");
  };
}

setInterval(updateMarquee, 1000);
setInterval(updateMarquee(), 10000);
```

```html
<marquee direction="right" scrollamount="10" behavior="alternate">
  <p id="boxContent">Marquees</p>
</marquee>
```

**Update:** In regard to user78403's answer, I've updated my code snippet to show the difference between calling the function itself in a `setInterval` and calling a functions return value. In the example you will see  `updateMarquee() has been called` logged every second because of the line `setInterval(updateMarquee, 1000);`. But you will also see `updateMarquee() return value was called instead of the function` logged every 10 seconds because of the line `setInterval(updateMarquee(), 10000);`

---

P.S. Don't use a marquee. Having anything automatically moving, playing,  changing on a website might have been mind-blowing 20 years ago, but now its just annoying and users *will* look down on your site for it. You should just have a static list of your job offerings that users can read through at their own pace.

Answer (score 1):

I corrected a few syntax errors in your code. I'll explain the most important things I've done:

- `setInterval(joobs(), 20000)` -> `setInterval(joobs, 20000)`: You have to
  pass the method itself as argument. Else the method will be called
  and its return value will be executed every 20 seconds.
- `Thejobs.Studies[ii]` -> `Thejobs.Studies["jobID" + ii]`: Give the property name as index. Passing a number doesn't work. It is also necessary to initialize `ii` with `1` instead of `0` because of the JSON file's property names.
- I also added some missing brackets.

HTML and JSON aren't changed.
So it all looks like this:

```
var myVar = setInterval(joobs, 20000);
var ii=1;
function joobs() {
    $.getJSON("jsons/jobs.json", function (json) {
        var Thejobs = json;
        $('#boxContent').append('<br>' + "position:" +
            Thejobs.Studies["jobID" + ii].position +
            '<br>' +
            "Academy: " +
            Thejobs.Studies["jobID" + ii].academy +
            '<br>' +
            "address: " +
            Thejobs.Studies["jobID" + ii].address +
            '<br>' +
            "Description:" +
            Thejobs.Studies["jobID" + ii].jobDescription);
        $('#boxContent').append("<br>_____________________");
    });
    ii = ii + 1;
}
```

Comment: > You have to pass the method itself as argument. Else the method will be called and its return value will be executed every 20 seconds. - That is really OPs mistake here, and a confusing one if you don't know what's going on. That is an excellent explanation.